# libGDX : Break Glass action

Tags: java, libgdx

In This Image [image: 1]
(Score Text on glass). 
In My libGDX game, I want to break this glass. 
I think if I want to make this action, I will use ParticleEditor But if I can import into it many image (But ParticleEditor import one image only).
Have anyone idea to make this action ?

Comment: Kinda broad question. Libgdx has a particle editor in its tools. Do you want to break up the score as well? If not I would cut up the glass and send each piece in a random direction. If you want the score to break as well you need to find a way to create an image from it and cut that on the fly.

Comment: Only break glass. Because i want to add scale action for score label (scale from 0 to 1) then score label break glass. That's it. Ya, your suggetion is well and i know it. But i asked this question, to find easy idea such as use particleEditor or other tool. Thanx for ur comment. Any another idea?